# Avoiding xss attack in struts2 application

Tags: javascript, java, html, struts2, xss

I am writing interceptor for avoiding xss attack in struts2 application. I handled `<script>` and other patterns. But I need small help in how to filter below xss alerts.

Sample code:

> ')(alert(document.domain))(' \

as parameter value.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Filtering for an `alert` is pointless--you need to handle *all* JavaScript, which is why you don't render un-processed user input, ever. If you're rendering into JS you can't just handle one trivial usecase, you need to handle *all of JS*. (And "handling `<script>`" is actually unlikely, since it can be broken up in a myriad of ways.)